# How can I bind the CSS background-image property?

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

Is it possible to make a style background-image binding?

I tried this code:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: itemList">
    <div data-bind="style: { background-image: 'url:(temp.png)' }">some text</div>          
</div>
```

I also tried `backgroundImage`, without quotes in `url`, without `:` after `url`, but it's still not working. All the others, like `color` or `backgroundColor` bindings are working perfectly.

Comment: Did you actually get binding to a property to provide the url to work?  From your example you have a hard coded url which I wouldn't use Knokout data-bind because you can use use style="background-image:...".    I'm trying to get binding to a property to provide the url.  I'm considering just including url:(temp.png) in the property as a hack.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As stated in the [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html), you need to use the Javascript name for the style you want to control.

This means that you would have to use `backgroundImage` instead of `background-image`.

Something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: itemList"> 
    <div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(temp.png)' }">some text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: i red the documentation, and there's also a link to most of the javascript style attributes too : http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html, it says use "regular" tag names for tags that don't have javascript names  :/

Comment: I know they use the single quotes for the `attr` binding and perhaps this works the same way now and the docs just aren't up to date. Actually, when I think about it I think I had problems with this one before.

Comment: Easy solution is to use a css class instead of  a style :-)

Comment: @John Papa I disagree... If you have multiple items with different images, that won't be feasible!

Comment: You can use the css names with hyphens by wrapping the whole name in quotes!

Answer (score 9):

I'm not sure why everyone (except Sujesh) is answering this question and still hard coding the `temp.png`.  If you are not binding to a `ko.observable` property then don't use `data-bind`. Just use the standard style property of the html element.

```
<div data-bind="foreach: itemList">
    <div style="background-image: url('temp.png');">some text</div>          
</div>
```

For data binding to get the url I wish Sujesh Arukil's answer worked for me but it didn't.  If anyone has that working, please enlighten me.

Here is what worked for me but I don't care for it.  I used a computed to get the value of the background-image.

In the view model

```
self.imageUrl = ko.observable();

self.bgImageUrlStyle = ko.computed(function() {
    return "url(" + self.imageUrl() + ")";
});
```

In the HTML

```
<div data-bind="style: { 'background-image': bgImageUrlStyle }">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

By the way, you can set up a custom binding to make the syntax less unwieldy:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.backgroundImage = {
  update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.style.update(element,
      function(){return {backgroundImage: "url('" + valueAccessor() + "')"}});
  }
};
```

Then in your HTML you can do

```
<div data-bind="backgroundImage: image"></div>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Clean, concise, and super easy to use & reuse.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need the `:` in the `url` section for a background image, it is just `url(/foo.png)`.

Your binding also needs to use `background-image` since that is the style property, but in quotes, like so (`backgroundImage` is the JavaScript API for style):

```
<div data-bind="style: { 'background-image': 'url(https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png)' }"></div>​
```

Live demo here - http://jsfiddle.net/slace/EgUaM/

**Edit** After posting the example Github started experiencing database issues so here's an alternate jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/slace/EgUaM/1/

Comment: Hi, that fiddle doesn't work for me? I tried your advice with quotes, but it's not working for me neither. In fact, i copied your code from fiddle, to load google image, still nothing?

Comment: Since posting it github has gone offline (according to https://status.github.com/) so it fails to load knockout into jsfiddle!

Comment: It's back online, but this jsfiddle is not functional. It accepts backgroundColor : http://jsfiddle.net/EgUaM/2/ and all the other tags, except background-image tag. @John Papa I know i can use class binding, but I need to use style binding  :)

Comment: @cs.tropic Use 'backgroundImage'. I know at least some browsers (e.g. Firefox) require this. I just tried it in your fiddle and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

or just concatenate

```
<div data-bind="style: { backgroundImage: 'url(\'' + $data.videoImg + '\')' }"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put quotes (single quotes) around the property name. whenever your have `-` in the property name e.g. `background-image` or `background-url` you need to put quotes around the name

```
<div data-bind="style: {'background-image' : 'url(somepath)'}>
```

That is the problem. Mentioned in the Knockout documentation.

Comment: Missing a double quote at the end?
btw, it doesn't work on my case.

Answer (score 0):

based on KO documentation,

VALUE to be SET to any Property in KO is ViewModal Property Value.

where somepath = ViewModal Property that is PATH to your background image.

Answer (score 0):

When there are two names, use the first name in lower case and the first character of the second name in upper case. Examples:

```
color = color
background-color = backgroundColor
font-style = fontStyle
font-weight = fontWeight
```

please refer to http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html
and http://www.comptechdoc.org/independent/web/cgi/javamanual/javastyle.html

Answer (score 0):

When u say: data-bind:"{...somecode...}" you need to understand that u are inside of javascript. If you write: background-image he tries to subtract image from background (background-image). Thats are undefined variables. Then it is much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

`<div  data-bind="style: { background: 'url(' + imageUrl + ')' }" ></div>`

The above one i used suppose to work.

If you use`background: 'url(imageUrl)'`, it will consider as a string only.